# Illegal characters in the path

Tags: c#, smtp, email-attachments, illegal-characters

I'm trying to send mail with attachments using smtp client.
Everything goes well when I'm trying to add an attachment like that:

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"C:\icon.jpg");
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

but when I try to read a path from the console like:

```
string path = Console.Read();
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path);
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

I'm getting the exception

> Illegal charcters in the path

Is there anyone who could explain to me why it doesn't work?

Comment: You want to read more than a single character, try `Console.ReadLine`

Comment: From [the Console.Read() doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.7.2): "_Reads_ _the_ _next_ _character_ _from_ _the_ _standard_ _input_ _stream_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that [Console.Read() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) is intended to read only the next character from the input.

You should use [Console.ReadLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_ReadLine) instead, which will read an entire line from the input.

```
string path = Console.ReadLine();
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path);
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: oh, thanks I see. Now it work, but when i try to pass this value it doesn't work

Comment: it works ok, until I try to pass this value to other function

Comment: If you have another problem but this answer fixes the "illegal characters in path" problem, you should consider marking this answer as helpfull and creating a new question with a [mcve] of the new problem.